# Why does my font seem so thin?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

My text in my PDF export just doesn't look right. This image is the best example. At 150% zoom on my PDF export, the left bracket does not look quite right. It's oddly thin.

[image: Thin bracket]

My preamble is as follows

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{parskip}
\author{Auth}
\date{\today}
\title{Title}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Auth}
 pdftitle={Title},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 29.1 (Org mode 9.6.6)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}
```

which line is to blame?

Other PDFs made from LaTeX look just fine. It's only this one that is effected.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: computer modern is thin, it's hard to tell from an image but it may be you do not have cm-super installed an so are using bitmap fonts, what does `pdffonts` program or acrobat font menu show as the document fonts? type1 or type3?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Highly varying. Every "name" beginning with "F" is Type 3. Everything else is Type 1.

Comment: well type3 means you have bitmap fonts, probably miktex as texlive has these by default, you can add cm super in the miktex console

Comment: @DavidCarlisle **Much** better. Feel free to post that as an answer.